# Why are there 2 Firefox icons in the launcher, and other issues

Tags: unity, firefox, launcher

All,

For some reason, a second launcher icon when I run Firefox:

(attempting to add image)

[image]

Has anyone seen this before?

Also: an open firefox window does not show up when cycling through applications using ALT+TAB...weird!

**EDIT:** After restarting, I was able to remove all firefox launcher icons. Now, however, when I opened firefox, there was NO launcher icon showing. Restarting firefox, now there is a launcher icon. Perhaps the problem is resolved...

-m

Comment: try this: remove both of them, close FF, start FF again, lock icon to launcher. succes

Comment: @user154126 Actually - the firefox launcher icon I originally locked doesn't even have an 'unlock' option. The new window I open can be locked and unlocked, but the original one is stuck!

Comment: try moving this icon to the trash

Comment: Restarted and now there is *no* launcher icon showing for an open Firefox window...

Comment: add a new icon (drag from dash) and start FF from there

Comment: @user154126 wow didn't know you could do that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had similar situation with chrome, where after installation of chrome web apps (gmail, gdocs etc), launcher would show a second chrome icon and when using the second icon chrome would not show using ALT+TAB. Although if starting chrome by original icon it would show cycling through applications using ALT+TAB

However my fix was unlock all chrome icons from launcher then start chrome and lock new icon to launcher. Duplicate icon did not show up again

Try it with FF, it may solve your duplicate icon too.