# 18.04: How do I make my apps "overlap" in Dash to Panel

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-dash

In Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, Firefox has two application icons instead of one. One just launches Firefox, and the other is the open application itself. How do I make it only have one icon?

[image: Screenshot]

**System info:**
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there 2 Firefox icons in the launcher, and other issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361149/why-are-there-2-firefox-icons-in-the-launcher-and-other-issues)

Comment: Is that really *Dash to Panel*? It just looks like Ubuntu Dock (the dock present by default in Ubuntu 18.04).